# How can I find the negations of the following propositions?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

a. : "2 + 2 = 4"

b. : "1 = 0"

c. r: "Diamonds are a pearl's best friend"

d. s: "All the politicians in this town are crooks"

Can someone help me with this? Been trying to solve it for hours but I don't understand how to do it. Would appreciate help:)

Comment: The negation of $p$ is $\lnot p$ and the negation of $q$ is $\lnot q$.

Comment: "All" is the *universal* quantifier; the negation of $\forall x$ is $\exists x \lnot$.

Comment: Obviously yes.... but the issue is: what have you to do ? Translate them into symbols ? Write them in plain English ?

Answer (score 0):

d.  There is an honest politician in this town.